# How to screen record higher than 1920x1080

Tags: display, video, quicktime, screen-capture, resolution

I just made a new app that I'm selling, and I'm using a mp4 video on the home page of the sales site. It looks pretty fuzzy on retina displays:

http://mapleapp.info

I've been capturing this video with QuickTime, but i can only export up to 1920x1080. All I need to do is export at a higher quality in order for it to look OK. I've found some third party solutions, but anything I've found that's capable of exporting video at higher than 1080 also comes with a hefty price tag (> $20). Now don't get me wrong, I'm all for paying for apps, but this is something that I'm going to use very rarely and I just can't justify paying that much for something that I'll only use on occasion.

Does anybody know of a way to screen record on a Mac and export at higher than 1080 quality? Preferably I'd like built in or free solutions, but I would be willing to pay for an app if it were less than $10. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to double check, but is your monitor larger than 1920x1080?

Comment: It's a 2015 retina Macbook, so I think my actual resolution is something in the 2300 range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the highest quality that I could export at using Quicktime was 1920 x 1080, however by saving it instead of exporting, I was able to achieve 2880 width. I then converted the video using ffmpeg with:

```
ffmpeg -i demo-video.mov demo-video.mp4
```

And I had a web ready video at 2880 width!

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search found one of my favorite tips for OS X: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131030130206132

Essentially, go to System Preferences > Displays, **option**-click the Scaled button, then select a  new resolution. Your QuickTime movie should record at the new resolution, but remember bigger resolutions take up more graphics power.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work in El Capitan. On a similar note, however, I also have DisplayMenu installed which allows me to select a bigger resolution. The problem is that QuickTime only allows export up to 1080. Also, All that this essentially does is make the content of my screen smaller. I then have to crop the video and size it up to fit correctly on the top of the home page of my site, which negates this shrinking effect. I need something that actually lets me export at a higher resolution, like screenflick, but not as expensive...